# How to semantically markup extra information to a input and label field

Tags: html, accessibility, forms, semantic-markup

I have a `label` extra description and an `input` field.

[image: label and input with description]

I am a bit unsure if the extra description belongs to the label field wrapped in a span like this:

```
<label for="phone">
    Telephone
    <span>For the delivery</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="phone">
```

This way the description is clickable. But I am not sure if this is the correct approach with a11y in mind and semantic markup.

Does the extra informations belong to the label or should it be separated and how should it be formatted?

Comment: @aardrian already answered your question. But speaking about accessibility, be careful about the text contrast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I always map the `<label>` to the `id` of the field instead of its `name` (particularly important for radio buttons and checkboxes):

```
<label for="phone">
 Telephone
 <span>For the delivery</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
```

Your approach is not wrong. If you are concerned about verbosity for screen readers (maybe as the result of user testing) then you can shuffle that a bit and use `aria-describedby`:

```
<label for="phone">
 Telephone
</label>
<span id="phoneAddl">For the delivery</span>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" aria-describedby="phoneAddl">
```

`aria-describedby` still associates it with the field, but announces it after the field and with a brief pause. It has not effect on anything other than a screen reader.

But to your point about the larger click area, and given that semantically it is fine to leave it in the `<label>`, I would just leave it there as in your example.

It also means you are not relying on ARIA to do the work of a native element (though it is not *quite* doing the same thing).

Comment: I would also prefer the first solution as the "for delivery" may be an important information that should be spoken with no delay.

Comment: In the first solution, test it with a few screen readers to hear how it sounds.  It might say "telephone for the delivery" as one continuous sentence.  You might be ok with how it sounds but visually, the "for the delivery" seems like a parenthetical phrase with less emphasis (since it's gray text instead of black).  You might want it to be read as a parenthetical phrase with a brief pause after "telephone" and then "for the delivery".  Aria-describedby will do that, as @aardrian said, but I too like the bigger click target by having it as one big label.  (continued...)

Comment: (continued...) You can trick the screen reader into pausing by adding a comma in your text.  However, you don't really want the comma displayed so it would have to be in an aria-label.  `<span aria-label=', for the delivery'>For the delivery</span>`.  But if you get to this point, you might be nit-picking the solution.  You probably have other bigger issues to spend time on.  I just wanted to point out the trick :-)